# Azure Data Factory Incremental Load data by using Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I would like to load incremental data from data lake into on premise SQL, so that i created data flow do the necessary data transformation and cleaning the data.

after that i copied all the final data sink to staging data lake to stored CSV format.

I am facing two kind of issues here.

1. when ever i am trigger / debug to loading my dataset(**data flow full activity** ), the first time data loaded in CSV, if I load second time similar pipeline, the target data lake, the CSV file loaded empty data, which means, the column header loaded but i could not see the any value inside file.
2. coming to **copy activity**, which is connected to on premise SQL server, i am trying to load the data but if we trigger this pipeline again and again, the duplicate data loaded, i want to load only incremental or if updated data comes from data lake CSV file. how do we handle this.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you please add information about the copy activity source and sink configurations. And also add the configurations of your datasets which are using as source and sink in your dataflow

Comment: copy activity source is dataset for adls gen2 csv format and sink is on premise sql server with out any pre copy script added.

Comment: dataset source - adls gen2 csv files

Comment: dataflow source is power apps location which means we are loading the files from adls gen2 and sink to connect dataset

Comment: Are you using incremental load based on only one key column? or are there any additional conditions?

Comment: any solution would be fine and now just copy the data from source dataset and put back to adls gen2, after that i am pulling the all the data into sql server as of now

Comment: i want push the data from copy to sql increment manager

Comment: Have you tried configured your sink by selecting `Upsert`. Look at this [reference image](https://i.imgur.com/jYMfaGv.png)

Comment: added image reference is not visible and restricting in my org computer, please share in images add in that questions.

Comment: i just now tried upsert and my target table now allowing primary key as dublicate, i updated manually source file(csv) to added one more column and id but if i run the copy pipeline and getting failed, it is seems to avoid duplicate column not allowing to insert in table.

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__opportun__3213E83FDFD49BA8'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.opportunity'. The duplicate key value is (21).,}

Comment: also i have setup in source sink UTC filter last modifier @adddays(utcnow(),-1) and end UTC @utcnow()... is it anything wrong. kindly advise

Comment: thanks so much after used upsert, now the incremental perfectly working.

Comment: Converting the above suggested approach as an answer so it helps other community members facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we want to incrementally load our data to a database table, we need to use the `Upsert` option in copy data tool.

**Upsert** helps you to incrementally load the source data based on a key column (or columns). If the key column is already present in target table, it will update the rest of the column values, else it will insert the new key column with other values.

Look at following demonstration to understand how `upsert` works. I used azure SQL database as an example.

**My initial table data:**

```
create table player(id int, gname varchar(20), team varchar(10))
```

[image]

**My source csv data (data I want to incrementally load):**

- I have taken an id which already exists in target table (id=1) and another which is new (id=4).

[image]

**My copy data sink configuration:**

- Create/select dataset for the target table. Check the `Upsert` option as your write behavior and select a key column based on which upsert should happen.

[image]

**Table after upsert using Copy data:**

- Now, after the `upsert` using copy data, the id=1 row should be updated and id=4 row should be inserted. The following is the final output achieved which is inline with expected output.

[image]

You can use the `primary key` in your target table (which is also present in your source csv) as the key column in `Copy data` sink configuration. Any other configuration (like source *filter by last modified* configuration) should not effect the process.

Comment: thanks lot, i made primary key source csv by using surrogate key.